# Efficiently authorizing a Client Credentials OAuth2ClientRequest in a multithreaded context with Spring Security 5.2+

Tags: spring-security

With the introduction of `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` in Spring Security 5.2, it's possible to handle the authorization of OAuth2 clients with HTTP clients or abstractions other than `WebClient`.

We could use something like

```
OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientManager.authorize(
    OAuth2AuthorizeRequest
        .withClientRegistrationId("registration-id")
        .principal("client-id")
        .build()
);
```

Reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8018#issuecomment-601183465

Although I can now get an access token from the `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` (e.g. `String accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue()`), I must always first call `authorizedClientManager.authorize(oAuth2AuthorizeRequest)` to ensure that I have a valid access token before calling a downstream service. If the access token is expired, the `authorize` call will perform a Client Credentials call to the token endpoint and get a response back with a fresh token. However, if my microservice receives multiple calls at the same time (e.g. on different request threads), the `authorize` call could theoretically call the token endpoint for every request thread because each request thread will determine that the access token is expired and request a new one before calling the downstream service. Only once the the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` is updated with a valid token, will the request threads stop invoking more token endpoint calls. Also, there may be a flurry of token endpoint responses that will overwrite each other with the final response's access token getting persisted in the the repository until the next expiration.

I'd like to find a way to efficiently authorize client credentials clients in a multithreaded context so that I don't trigger a race condition of token requests. The only ways around this that I can think of is to schedule authorizations before the access token expires or for Spring Security to prevent multiple token endpoint calls if it's waiting for the first response.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same exact issue here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't find a solution. It's still an open issue. However, in practice, it hasn't seemed to create noticeable problems.